# Custom alphanumerical values in chart.js?

Tags: javascript, html, web, chart.js

I am trying to make a simple horizontal bar chart with [Chart.js](http://www.chartjs.org/) with some languages ('Spanish', 'English', ...) in the y-axis and its [CEFR Level](http://www.examenglish.com/CEFR/cefr.php) (from A1 to C2) in the x-axis instead of some numerical level (1-10 for example).

Is there a way to have a bar chart without pure numerical values in the x-axis?

[image: What I'm getting right now]

That is what I'm getting right now with this code:

```
var spokenLangChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'horizontalBar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Spanish', 'English', 'German'],
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'CEF Level',
                        labels: ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2'],
                        data: ['C2', 'C1', 'B1'],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So thanks to Julian Schmuckli I was able to fix this. Since it wasn't entirely solved I'm going to post my own answer so I can share the result.

```
var ctx = document.getElementById('spokenLangChart').getContext('2d');
            var xLabels = ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2'];
            var spokenLangChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'horizontalBar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Spanish', 'English', 'German'], //Put here your x labels
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'CEF Level',
                        data: [5, 4, 3],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    legend: {
                        position: 'bottom'
                    },
                    title: {
                        display: true,
                        text: 'Spoken Languages'
                    },
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                beginAtZero: true,
                                //Returns the x labels
                                callback: function (value, index, values) {
                                    return xLabels[index];
                                }
                            }
                        }]
                    }
                }

            });
```

It's very important that you put `beginAtZero: true`, otherwise it will put your lowest value as zero and as I hadn't numerical values it was a bit difficult to spot the error.

Here's the final result:

[image: Final result]

Answer (score 2):

Currently, ChartJS does not support directly two axis without numerical values. But you can accomplish this with callbacks as you can see on my example:

```js
var ctx = document.getElementById('chart');

var xLabels = ["A","B","C","D","E","F","G","H","I","J","K"]; //Put here your x labels

var spokenLangChart = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'horizontalBar',
                data: {
                    labels: ['Spanish', 'English', 'German'], //Put here your x labels
                    datasets: [{
                        label: 'CEF Level',
                        labels: ['A1', 'A2', 'B1', 'B2', 'C1', 'C2'],
                        data: ['C2', 'C1', 'B1'],
                        backgroundColor: "rgba(255,153,0,0.4)"
                    }]
                },
                options: {
                    scales: {
                        xAxes: [{
                            ticks: {
                                //Returns the x labels
                                callback: function(value, index, values) {
                                    return xLabels[index];
                                }
                            },
                        }]
                    },
                },
                
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/2.5.0/Chart.min.js"></script>
<canvas id="chart" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
```

Or look at [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/c26uej8g/).

I hope it helps you.

Comment: Had to tweak a little bit more, but it really helped! Will post the complete solution soon, thanks!